# Wrong page title in unanswered list questions page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

There seems to be a problem of title management on SO:

In fact, the title displayed when visiting the [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Unanswered) page on SO is "Highest Votes Questions", instead of "Unanswered Questions". The problem is also here for the [Unanswered (my tags)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tab=Unanswered&tagMode=Watched) and Unanswered with custom tag ([ex with "css"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css?tab=Unanswered)) pages.

[image: Wrong title of "unanswered questions" list page example]

---

If you visit any other "filter" page there is no problem; i.e. the correct title is displayed.

---

**Edit:** The bug seems to be on all the SE network websites ([ex1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Unanswered), [ex2](https://askubuntu.com/questions?tab=Unanswered), [ex3](https://superuser.com/questions?tab=Unanswered)...).

Comment: Reported and fixed on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330621/wrong-page-title-in-unanswered-list-questions-page).